# Vexing regex pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

I have some malformed json strings that I am trying to fix.  To accomplish that I was planning on splitting the string up into tokens, fixing each token when necessary and then recombine the tokens into a valid json string.  Steps two and three are working great, it is the first step, tokenizing the string, that is causing me problems.

Here is an (highly edited) example of one of these strings:

```
userId: "someUserId"
application: "some Application"
request: {
  strategy: 1
  locations: [
    {
      locationId: "1"
    }
    {
      locationId: "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to tokenize it so that I have an array like this:

```
userId:
"someUserId"
application:
"some Application"
request:
{
strategy:
1
locations:
[
{
locationId:
"1"
}
{
locationId:
"2"
}
]
}
```

I can get really close using this simple regex pattern `\s+` like this:

```
$tokens = $json -split '\s+'
```

The only problem with that is that is splits strings with spaces so `"some Application"` becomes:

```
"some
Application"
```

I have struggled for a while now to turn that simple pattern into something magical that will do exactly what I want but so far that has only yielded results that are, frankly, too embarrassing to post.

Comment: Try [`\s+(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/xJ4fU5/1). This might not cope with huge strings though. The proper way is to use a *matching* regex. Like [`(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1|\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/xJ4fU5/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the other answers are not giving the results that I am looking for so I am going to throw my own answer in the ring.  This appears to do exactly what I want:

```
$tokens = $json -split '(?<=[\[\]{}:"]|[\[\]{}:][^"]+)\s+'
```

I will leave this question open for a bit until I am sure I did not miss some edge case.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working with the following:

```
(?m)(?:^|(?<=[:\{\[]))[\r\s]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NzkQ-LmEn4KZtTMF)

But I'm not certain it will work in every case you might come across (it works on your sample data).

#### Breakdown

`(?m)` puts it in multiline mode which lets `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of each line (as opposed the whole string).

Then I'm alternating between the beginning of a line (`^`) or a lookbehind for the characters `:`, `{`, or `[`, before finally matching the one or more whitespace.

To explain further:

`(?:)` this is the same as just using parentheses, except it's a non-capturing group. It's just a slight efficiency boost; you don't need to capture the contents, we only want it for alternation with `|`.

`(?<=)` this is a lookbehind, a zero-width match (whatever it matches won't be included as part of the match, but it must be true to proceed).

`[:\{\[]` this is just a character class, matching a single character that must be one of the ones specified. `\{` is used to represent a literal `{`, same with `\[` (they're escaped).

The lookbehind is used so that the preceding character exists but isn't part of the match (otherwise it would be consumed in the split).

Based on your comment, I changed `\s+` to `[\r\s]+` to match carriage returns.

Comment: Whoa!  Okay, there is some stuff going on there I have not seen before.  I will have to study this for a minute.

Comment: @JasonBoyd added a bit more, let me know if some of it still needs explanation.

Comment: I think this might be the right track but I am getting some weird results in PowerShell.  I would expect `$tokens[1]` to be `"someUserId"` but instead I am getting `"someUserId"\`rapplication:`.

Comment: @JasonBoyd I guess `\s` doesn't match carriage return (but does match the linefeed portion of CRLF), so I modified it a bit.

Comment: I am still getting the same result with that.  If you leave out this: `(?:^|(?<=[:\{\[]))` then I get what I expect for `$tokens[1]` but of course I am back to my strings getting split.

Comment: Okay, I did not completely grok `(?m)` at first.  I thought it caused the regex to match the pattern on each line individually.  But now that I understand it it is clear why I am not getting the expected result.  It is not matching the new line between "someUserId"` and `application:` because that character is not preceded by the beginning of a line (`^`) or any of the characters in the set `:[{`.  So this is close but not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

So you wish to tokenize the sample string, capturing `word:`, `"word"`, `numbers`, and parenthesis and brackets.

```
([\w"]+\s?[\w]*:?)|([{}\[\]])
```

will capture those groups, including `"word words"`. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/fW0sY1) is a demo.

Breakdown. First group will get the words, with an optional space, and zero or more words following, with an optional `:`.

Second group will capture all of the brackets and parentheses.

Using a `findall` or `gm` should get you all matches.